# AngularJS scope values undefined but API is working fine

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I don't get any error message, but while debugging Scope values are not binding it shows Undefined...**

Controller:

```
$scope.companyModify = function () {
    var param = {
        companyId:$scope.companyId,
        companyName:$scope.companyName,
        billPrintLinesTop:$scope.billPrintLinesTop,
        billPrintLinesBottom:$scope.billPrintLinesBottom,
        isPrintHeader:$scope.isprintHeader,
        billTypeId:$scope.billTypeId,
        billColumnId :$scope.billColumnId,
        noOfCopies: $scope.noOfCopies,
        billHeaderAlignmentId: $scope.billHeaderAlignmentId,
        billTitle: $scope.billTitle,
        billSortOrderId:$scope.billSortOrderId,
        posDefaultQty:$scope.posDefaultQty,
        posTaxTypeId:$scope.posTaxTypeId,
        isAllowNegativeStock:$scope.isAllowNegativeStock,
        serviceTaxCalcTypeId : $scope.serviceTaxCalcTypeId,
        wishMessage:$scope.wishMessage,
        coinageBy:$scope.coinageBy,
        isAutoGenerateProductCode:$scope.isAutoGenerateProductCode
    };

    console.log(param);
```

Calling the companyModify Function :
Open braces of companyModify closes in SocketService...

```
   SocketService.post(apiManage.apiList['CompanyModify'].api,param).
     then(function (resp) {
       var data = resp.data.response;

       if (data.status === true) {
            angular.forEach($scope.companyList, function (value) {
                 if (value.companyId == $scope.companyId) {
                    value.$edit = false;
                 }
        });

            Notify.alert(data.message, {
                status: 'success',
                pos: 'top-right',
                timeout: 5000
            });
            $scope.load();

        }
        else {
            Notify.alert(data.message, {
                status: 'danger',
                pos: 'top-right',
                timeout: 5000
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: can you add more details?

Comment: could you please provide your code in a plunker or fiddle, which will help us find the root cause

Comment: I think you have to return the param

Comment: @ Sridhar  still get same error sir..

Comment: @ Pramod_Para sir i'm new to angular i dont know how to use plunker..

Comment: Could you update complete code so that we can look into it?

Comment: @ Pramod_Para sir here is link to the code.. https://plnkr.co/edit/KOSOlbLFsJCuHCAwVjsH

Answer (score 0):

Ensure $scope is properly injected in controller

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  ...
  $scope.aMethod = function() {
  ...
  }
  ...
}]);
```

In your html code, input values are binded to `company.XXX` :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="company.posTaxTypeId" placeholder="Enter POSTaxCalculation"  >
```

If you want your code to work is the controller, you must use the same binding and use `posTaxTypeId: $scope.company.posTaxTypeId` instead of `posTaxTypeId: $scope.posTaxTypeId`

or change your html code to :

```
<span data-ng-show="!company.isEdit" data-ng-bind="posTaxTypeId"></span>
<span data-ng-show="company.isEdit"> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="posTaxTypeId" placeholder="Enter POSTaxCalculation"  >
</span>
```

also ensure that binding are declared properly, without spaces :

**bad**

```
data-ng-bind="company.posTaxTypeId "
ng-model="company.posTaxTypeId "
```

**good**

```
data-ng-bind="company.posTaxTypeId"
ng-model="company.posTaxTypeId"
```

Comment: @KumareshRoy please provide the full code of your controller

Comment: here is the link for full code sir.. plnkr.co/edit/KOSOlbLFsJCuHCAwVjsH

Comment: There is no spaces between *ng-model* attributes and *placeholder* attributes in html code, could you fix this and check again ?

`ng-model="company.companyName"placeholder`

Comment: @KumareshRoy please provide an updated version of your code after applying the changes. Maybe you forgot something.

Comment: You didn't apply the changes I told you. In your html code, there are still plenty of `ng-model="company.xxx"` instead of  `ng-model="xxx"`. Remember your `param` object values still point to `scope` properties, not `scope.company` properties. For example : `ng-model=company.billPrintLinesTop` binding in html code but `param: { billPrintLinesBottom:$scope.billPrintLinesBottom }` is used in controller

Comment: This cannot work without fixing this because when you enter value for `billPrintLinesTop ` in textbox it's binded to `scope.company.billPrintLinesTop`, not `scope.billPrintLinesTop`

Comment: @ stej4n  After updating your corrections i still get undefined error... I don't get any error message but since values are not updated to database... And Thanks a lot for Your kind help sir... I am still checking to sort out the error..updated code link here:**https://plnkr.co/edit/m9CewdvCyYtP1HmoVOzr?p=preview**

Comment: Please update you plunker with the FULL html code, from <html> to </html>, I can only see an extract of your code, it's very difficult to guess what could be wrong

Comment: @ stej4n Actually tat is the full html code , i have used html open,close tag in index.html... using routing function ..here added updated code :**https://plnkr.co/edit/nqQJqR?p=preview**